# Prevent mshtml from loading external resources

Tags: vbscript, mshtml

When I load an html file into mshtml, it seems to load external resources such as .js, and .css. How can I stop mshtml from loading external resources? Is there a setting in the registry for IE?

```
Dim mshtml: Set mshtml = CreateObject("htmlfile") 
mshtml.write "<html>...</html>"
```

I'd like a solution for IE 6+ (though any will be helpful!)

Comment: i tried this and didn't get the extra files, can you publish more of your code ? do you mean just the script and style tags ? where do you see the files ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "load external resources". It's not at all clear what's actually happening based on the code you've given.

Comment: Let me see if I get this: You've got a running MSHTML app. You've loaded in an HTML file which has embedded <script> and <img> and similar tags. You don't want those other items to execute. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hunting through [Geoff Chappell](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/ie/mshtml/index.htm?tx=36)'s site myself, trying to find an answer to this question. If you find something before I do, please post it here.